# Electrical potential difference?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

What is the electrical potential difference and why we have to talk about a difference and not about the electrical potential itself? What is the electrical potential difference in practical terms (can you explain it using concrete example?)
Please help me with a very clear explanation. (sorry for the numerous questions)

Comment: Potential is arbitrary up to a constant. Every elementary physics book explains this.

Comment: yes but my book doesn't give me any practical example of what is the electrical potential so that I can figure out what really I'm talking about and why. I just know what is the  definition of Electrical potential difference but I only want to have a more useful explanation.

Comment: A good place to start is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential

Comment: wikipedia says exactly what my book says (before I asked the question I had read it). Probably my question seems to be too elementaty...

Comment: Do you understand that the value of potential is arbitary, so it only matters the difference $E =-\nabla (V + k) =-\nabla V$, that the electric field points to where the potential is lower, etc?  If you understand the wiki article I think you know enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the electrical potential difference and why we have to talk
>   about a difference and not about the electrical potential itself?

Mathematically, the reason is that the *force* is proportional the *gradient* of **a** (not **the**) potential function.

$$\vec F = -\nabla \phi$$

Note that a potential that differs by an additive constant

$$\phi' = \phi + C$$

yields the same force field

$$\nabla \phi' = \nabla \phi$$

since the gradient of a constant is zero

$$\nabla C = 0$$

In other words, *adding an arbitrary constant to a potential does not change the physics so the absolute value of the potential is physically unmeaningful*.

But look at the difference in potential between two points:

$$\phi'(\vec x_1) - \phi'(\vec x_2) =  \phi(\vec x_1) + C - \phi(\vec x_2) - C = \phi(\vec x_1) - \phi(\vec x_2)$$

So, the potential difference is unchanged by the additive constant and thus the difference *is* physically meaningful.

> What is the electrical potential difference in practical terms (can
>   you explain it using concrete example?)

In practical terms, the electric potential difference between two points is the amount of work associated with moving a 1 Coulomb test charge from one of the points to the other.

Comment: This is what I want to know.In particular the answer of the first question in which you report things that are not mentioned in my book. Thank you !